# Prevent direct access of downloaded file in CI

Tags: codeigniter

How to prevent direct access to my download file using CodeIgniter.

Supposed I stored all of my file in

application/secretdirectory/file1.jpg
application/secretdirectory/file2.text
application/secretdirectory/file3.zip

usually, I create direct link to access these files.

```
<a href="application/secretdirectory/file3.zip" > download here </a>
```

I want to prevent it, I want my link will be

```
<a href="<? echo site_url() . "download/file3.zip"  ?>" > download here </a>
```

can you help me ???

Comment: They are directly accessing it when they click the download link, aren't they?

Comment: Oh ..., I'm sorry. I'm newbe, I think this website as only media for ask and answer. 

Next time, I will accept all of answer of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a good idea to pass it to a controller like this:

```
Class File extends Controller{

    function download($file){
        $data = file_get_contents('path/to/' . $file); // Read the file's contents
        $name = $file;
        force_download($name, $data);
    }
}
```

Your link would be:

```
<?php echo anchor('file/download/' . $thefile, 'Download');?>
```

This way they'd *never* know which directory it came from.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a library in CI to assist with this

basically you send headers for the correct MIME type, the content length (`filesize()`) and then output to the browser to download echo `file_get_contents()` may work)

If using Apache, you'll also want to deny showing directoy content.

```
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>
```